# Change matcher in Rspec 1.3 don't recognizes equal objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, comparison, matcher

I have that rspec test

```
let(:document) { Document.new }
let(:residue)  { Residue.new  } 

describe "inner_residue=" do
  before do
    document.producer_residue = residue
  end

  it 'dont changes the producer residue' do
    expect { document.inner_residue = residue }.to_not change(document, :producer_residue)
  end
end
```

That outputs this error:

```
producer_residue should not have changed, but did change from #<Residue id: nil, un_code: nil, description: "res", created_at: ... > to #<Residue id: nil, un_code: nil, description: "res", created_at: ... >
```

As you see, there is the same residue. 
The method its more complicated, but this one is a simplication that fails too:

```
def inner_residue=(other)
  return self.producer_residue = self.addressee_residue = nil unless other
  self.producer_residue = producer_residue
end
```

So... WTF?

Changing a residue for itself makes the assertion fails? I've checked if they are the same residue with ==, ===, eq? an its always true. I can't understand whats wrong with this.

I'm using rspec 1.3 (its an rails 2.3 app, I cant upgrade to rspec2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RSpec has no problem with objects that are equal. The problem here is that in ActiveRecord, two unsaved models are not considered equal, even if they have all the same properties. You can see this if you run `puts (Residue.new == Residue.new)`.

You'll have to save the Residue object for this to work.

Comment: But 
  let(:residue)  { Residue.new  }
should memoize the residue, so it should be always the same instance.

r = Residue.new; puts (r == r); #=> true

Comment: OK - I see what's going on here - the `change` matcher is designed specifically for numbers. The example is failing on line https://github.com/dchelimsky/rspec/blob/master/lib/spec/matchers/change.rb#L21, even though you don't get a very good failure message.

Comment: I'd recommend just expecting `document.producer_residue.should == residue`.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much! I had no idea that change was for number. I've used it lots of times with strings!! F**k!